# Postgres Hstore conact not working from other schema

Tags: postgresql

The following works

```
select public.hstore('new_users', 'a');
```

But this does not work

```
select public.hstore('new_users', 'a') || public.hstore('a', 'a');
```

Error

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: public.hstore || public.hstore
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 40
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: public.hstore || public.hstore
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 40
```

Comment: Please try this: `select public.hstore('new_users', 'a') operator(public.::) public.hstore('a', 'a')` — it looks like the `public.hstore`s themselves work, but your current schema doesn't have the `::` operator for them, but you can either import it or [refer explicitly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) with `operator(public.::)`.

Comment: If first statement is working then second will definitely work. What is the version of your postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion from comments

this is working fine

```
select public.hstore('new_users', 'a') operator(public.||) public.hstore('a', 'a')
```